# How to highlight the content if same attribute values are equal using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If the same attribute values are presenting in the html file, how can do find and highlight the content.

**For e.g.:**

```
<p>Quiz 1 </p>
<input class="radioclass" id="q1a" value="a" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">1</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q1b" value="b" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">2</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q1c" value="c" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">3</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q1d" value="d" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">4</input>
<p>Quiz 2</p>
<input class="radioclass" id="q2a" value="a" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">1</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q2b" value="b" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">2</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q2c" value="c" name="question[q3correct]" type="radio">3</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q2d" value="d" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">4</input>
<p>Quiz 3</p>    
<input class="radioclass" id="q2a" value="a" name="question[q3correct]" type="radio">1</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q2b" value="b" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">2</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q2c" value="c" name="question[q3correct]" type="radio">3</input>
<input class="radioclass" id="q2d" value="d" name="question[q1correct]" type="radio">4</input>
```

In the above mentioned codes, few name values are the same. In this case, how to highlight with background color or any other way using Javascript or Jquery?

Could you please someone help me to solve this? It will be appreciate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gfvoecdt/1/ ?

Comment: you cant do without `label` or `span` for lables(1,2,3,..)

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you @Arun P Johny, its cool, but i could not use it. I am using like this `<div id="d17" class="fnt63 text17"><input tabindex="1" class="cha" name="radio14a" type="radio" id="c529811_opt_0"/>abcd1234</div>
<div id="d20" class="fnt63 text20"><input tabindex="1" class="cha" name="radio14a" type="radio" id="c529811_opt_1"/>abcd1234</div>
<div id="d23" class="fnt63 text23"><input tabindex="1" class="cha" name="radio14a" type="radio" id="c529811_opt_2"/>abcd1234.</div>` I have tried, its not working to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using jquery, You can do it as follows:

```
$(":input").each(function({
    var myName = $(this).attr("name");

    if(myName == "question[q1correct]"){
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }else if(myName == "question[q3correct]"){
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, The name values will be match with others name value. If it will be the same value, it should be highlighted. because the name values are differ from users, thatswhy.